# Modulo 2 addition in dense layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am implementing a neural network to find code in a binary field. The layer essentially learns the generator matrix (at least tries to), and then code is obtained at the output. For any input `u`, the codeword `c` is obtained as `c = matmul(u.T, G)`. Since the space is a binary field, `1 + 1 = 0` and not `2`. The generator matrix also contains only `0's` and `1's`. I enforce this by using a kernel constraint. Now I have the following layers for a `(21, 11)` code:

```py
out1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=message, units=21, activation=None)
out2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=out1, units=21, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

The first layer's output `out1` has some `2's` and at times `3's` too. When this goes into the second layer, all the `2's` are converted into values close to `1` (`3's` don't face that problem).

What I'd like to know is if there is any method to have a modulo-2 addition in the dense layer. Any help is appreciated.